# Why is my WiFi password not recognized as correct?

Tags: wireless

I recently downloaded an Ubuntu operating system, dual booting with my windows 7.

When I try to connect to the internet on Ubuntu, it asks my password, closes, reopenes, and asks for it again.  This is a continuous process and I can't connect to the internet.

Answer (score 0):

I can think of two things that could cause this. This could happen if the network password is entered incorrectly. Enable the show password option and double check that the password is correct. Also make sure you have the right security method selected. In most cases it is "WPA & WPA Personal" but in some cases it could be another option. Check your router WiFi settings or the connection information on another machine that is successfully connected.

Also if you are using WEP pass phrase or WEP hex make sure you enter the password in correct format. A common error is to select WEP pass phrase but enter a Hex password which will be interpreted as incorrect and you will be prompted again.

Hope this helps.